# ZLIB returns different byte values after a compression and decompression

Tags: compression, gzip, zlib, lossless-compression, nifti

I have a 3d ndarray that I want to decompress using Zlib.
I use this part of the code to compress.

```
begin = 0
blockSize = 1024
compressImage = bytes('', 'utf-8')
while begin < len (nii_img1_data):
     compressImage = compressImage + 
                 compressImageObject.compress(nii_img1_data[begin:begin+blockSize])
     begin += blockSize
compressImage = compressImage + compressImageObject.flush()

f = open('compressed.dat', 'wb')
f.write(compressImage)
f.close()
```

and my decompression part is

```
decompressedImageObject = zlib.decompressobj(wbits=+15)
my_file = open('compressed.dat', 'rb').read()  
decompressedImage = zlib.decompress(my_file, bufsize=blockSize)
decompressedImage += decompressedImageObject.flush()
decompressedImage = np.frombuffer(decompressedImage, dtype=np.int8)
```

Before Compression the original image has a shape (90, 104, 72).
After decompression, the byte size returns 5391360 bytes which is higher than 90*104*72 = 673920 bytes.

I converted the decompressed into ndarray yielding a 1d array using

```
decompressedImage = np.frombuffer(decompressedImage, dtype=np.int8)
```

and trying to convert to the same shape of original image

```
decompressedImage = np.reshape(decompressedImage, newshape=(-1,104,72))
```

returns an array of shape = (720,104,72)

What am I doing wrong? How do I fetch the original image?

Comment: What data type is `newImage`, what dimensions does it have? What is `nii_img1_data`? Currently you're doing several things all at once without showing us all of them, and it's not really possible for us to know whether the problem is in the compression/decompression or in the conversion to bytes and back. I suggest you work first on creating a minimal reproducible example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have modified the code to suggest that nii_img1_data is the original image that I want to compress and decompress. The datatype is ndarray and the dimensions are (90,104,72)

Comment: What's the dtype of the original array? I assumed it was np.int8 because that's what you used to call frombuffer, but if it's not that could be an issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the behaviour you are describing. However, I can observe some problems.

```
while begin < len (nii_img1_data):
     compressImage = compressImage + 
                 compressImageObject.compress(nii_img1_data[begin:begin+blockSize])
     begin += blockSize
```

You indicate that `nii_img1_data` is an ndarray with dimensions (90,104,72). However, this code appears to assume it's a `bytes` object or something very similar. `len(nii_img1_data)` will return the size of the first dimension, 90. Slicing it with `nii_img1_data[0:1024]` will return the whole thing because the first dimension has size smaller than 1024. Feeding the slice to `zlib.Compress.compress` accesses the array's underlying buffer, the size of which will depend on exactly how you acquired the array, and may contain more data than the array itself. I'm *guessing* in your case `nii_img1_data` is a slice of a larger array, since that might explain what happens next. Alternatively perhaps it has a dtype other than `np.int8`?

Once you've fed this buffer to zlib, it appears that the loop runs only once because `len(nii_img1_data)` is only 90. When you decompress, you rebuild the data that was in the buffer, it's just not the data that you expected.

I suggest you make sure you convert your array to bytes or a buffer *first* and that even before you try to compress or decompress it you verify that you are able to convert those bytes back into the ndarray that you expect. Only once you're satisfied should you then add compression into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous, but I found this question when I had the same question. here is the answer I found.

If you look at the definition for `zlib.compress()`

```py
def compress(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """
    Returns a bytes object containing compressed data.
    
      data
        Binary data to be compressed.
      level
        Compression level, in 0-9 or -1.
    """
    pass
```

You will see there is 10 different levels of compression if you decompress with zlib you have to match the compression if you want to go back.

```py
zlib.compress( zlib.decompress(byte_data), -1 ) == byte_data # False
zlib.compress( zlib.decompress(byte_data), 0 ) == byte_data # False
zlib.compress( zlib.decompress(byte_data), 1 ) == byte_data # True
zlib.compress( zlib.decompress(byte_data), 2 ) == byte_data # False
zlib.compress( zlib.decompress(byte_data), 3 ) == byte_data # False
# etc..
```

You will be able to find the compression level of your default byte data this way.